# filtered file type search and delete java

Tags: java, file

This code is at the address I gave me ".txt " lists the name of the files.

I want to delete these files without printing them to the screen.
And is it possible to do this in a function, not in two separate classes?

```java
public class file {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("D:/Users"); 
        String[] allFiles = f.list(new MyFilter ());
        for (String filez:allFiles ) {
            f.delete();
        }
    }
}

class MyFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
        return((name.endsWith(".txt")));        
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `for` you delete the root file, not the `.txt` files

Comment: Nothing in your code snippets prints to the screen? Thus I am not sure what you are asking about? Also note: `file` is a really really bad name. Why not `TextFileDeleter` or something alike (class names go UpperCamelCase, and they should be meaningful, and not carry the same name as java library classes)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code deletes all the files with txt extension inside a folder.

```
public class file {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       File folder = new File("D:/Users");

        for (File f : folder.listFiles()) 
        {
             if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) 
             {
                f.delete(); 
             }
        }
   }
}}
```